# Can I discover what processor socket I have via software

Tags: processor-socket

I am running a windows-8 laptop with an AMD E2 processor. I want to find out what socket I have (AM-2, AM-3, AM-3+) but I do not want to have to crack open the laptop. Is there a way using built in windows tools, that I can discover what my socket is? Is there some other software that can tell me this?

Comment: `Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. ....` If you remove your last sentence it will probably be on topic again and you're still likely to get the type of answer you want :)

Comment: Just look up the processor on AMD's website.  The socket isn't really something software should be aware of.  There are tons ( I would estimate it at over a hundred ) free pieces of software which will identify the exact processor you have.

Comment: I'd just google the processor. I *suspect* its a soldered in, BGA processor tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"CPU-ID" is free software that will provide all details about your hardware including which Socket your cpu is using.